# elements wont .fadeTo in my code. Don't know what's wrong JavaScript, JQuery, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout, fadeto

I am trying to get the buttons in my code (the only two buttons) with the class names "play" and "credits" to fade out when they are clicked using JQuery but it is not working. Please tell me what is wrong.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="startMen">
    <div class="playDiv">
        <button class='play'>Play</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="creditsDiv">
        <button class='credits'>Credits</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play, .credits').click(function(){
        $('.play, .credits').fadeTo('slow',0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing your jQuery `fadeTo` method to `fadeOut`

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the `<head>` section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery hasn't been linked to you HTML. Add it to the head somewhere before your link to your script.js so the rest of your Javascript can use the JQuery library as well.

Should be:

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't link `jQuery`. This means the browser has no idea what `jQuery` is. You have to add the `<script>` tag.

Use the following in your `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/afek6mh7/)
Your code actually works, just a simple mistake :)

---

You can also use `.fadeOut()` instead of `.fadeTo()`. It's more simple. Take a look at that [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

---

'Cause I'm posting an answer, you can use `$(function () {` as short for `$(document).ready(function(){`. I know it's not related but just mentioning ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JQuery library in your script. It's hosted on the Google CDN.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As a side note, while you can use .fadeTo();

.fadeTo() 
requires duration and opacity as arguments. a.e:

```
.fadeTo("slow", .5);
```

If you're looking for it to fade into displaying nothing you could use the method .fadeOut(); and pass a duration argument. a.e. :

```
.fadeOut("slow");
```

Edit: When I first read the script my eyes skipped over the 0 in the fadeTo method. I assumed that was the issue. After throwing it through jsfiddle, it seems like the problem was the library missing.

Comment: @vihan1086 I figured that out after I threw it in jsfiddle. When I initially read it I skipped the 0 in the fadeTo argument.